# Testing TypeScript generated class with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

As the title says, I want to test a TypeScript class I wrote using Jasmine (at least I assume I can't test the `.ts` file directly?). I guess the reason could be the way TypeScript compiled the `.js` file.

So when I run `jasmine spec/movieSpec.js`, I get the following error:

```
Suite error: Movie
  Message:
    TypeError: Movie is not a constructor
  Stack:
        at <Jasmine>
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Coding/TypeScript/mediaparser/spec/movieSpec.js:4:15)
        at <Jasmine>
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Coding/TypeScript/mediaparser/spec/movieSpec.js:3:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
No specs found
Finished in 0.004 seconds
Randomized with seed 40039 (jasmine --random=true --seed=40039)
```

Here are my other files:

**src/movie.ts**

```
export class Movie {
  private name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name.replace(".mkv", "");
  }
}
```

**dist/movie.js** (generated)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class Movie {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name.replace(".mkv", "");
    }
}
exports.Movie = Movie;
```

**spec/movieSpec.js**

```
const Movie = require('../dist/movie');

describe("Movie", function() {
  let movie = new Movie("aMovie.mkv");

  it("removes the file extension", function() {
    expect(movie.name).toEqual("aMovie")
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

**Update**
I've changed the `target` in `tsconfig.json` to `"ES2016"`, which results in a slightly different `movie.js`. I've updated the code accordingly. Unfortunately the error is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your spec/movieSpec.js, try changing the require statement to:

```
const Movie = require('../dist/movie').Movie;
```

I think that your require statement doesn't return the actual Movie class.
You can also check this out by checking what is the actual value of your Movie const

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I didn't come to this conclusion myself. When I now look at `exports.Movie = Movie;` from `movie.js` it's kind of obvious. Thanks a lot! By the way, could I write this `require` statement in another way? I guess I can't use `import` instead of `require` here?